# How to assign a string ending in <CR> to a vimscript variable without it adding a <LF>?

Tags: macros, special-characters, vim, macvim

I have been playing around with vim macros lately (in MacVim at the moment), and sometimes I like to explicitly assign a macro into a register using e.g. `:let @a='(macro keystrokes)'`.  This is generally working fine, but I found a weird behavior in which anytime I assign a string value that ends in Carriage Return / ^M, vim automatically adds a Linefeed / ^J to the end before putting it in the register, which affects the execution of the macro!

Example:  Let's say I record a simple macro that gets into insert mode, types "hey", escapes out of insert mode, and then hits Enter twice to go down 2 lines.  I record this into register @a by typing `qaihey<Escape><Enter><Enter>q`, which stores the following in @a:

```
ihey^[^M^M
```

So far so good, and executing the macro by typing `@a` does just what it's supposed to.  Another perfectly ok way I can get this same macro into register @a would be by typing the whole thing (`ihey<Ctrl-V><Escape><Ctrl-V><Enter><Ctrl-V><Enter>`) into a buffer and then yanking it with `"ay` -- the end result is just the same.  But here's the weird thing -- suppose I just wanted to assign that string directly into @a using a `let` statement:

```
:let @a='ihey^[^M^M'
```

Now if I type `:reg` to look at the value it says there's an extra `^J` on the end for some reason:

```
"8     ...
"9     ...
"a     ihey^[^M^M^J
"b     ...
```

Having the extra `^J` causes it to go down an extra line when I execute the macro, so it's actually changing the behavior.

Anybody know why this extra character is being added?  Anyone know how I can get a string value ending with `^M` into a register (or any variable), without having an extra `^J` get added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some quick checking the vim help files says this:

> ```
> :let @{reg-name} = {expr1}            *:let-register* *:let-@*
>
> ...
> If the result of {expr1} ends in a <CR> or <NL>, the
> register will be linewise, otherwise it will be set to
> characterwise.
> ```

In other words, ending the string with a carriage return will make Vim interpret it as a line ending

---

Quick googling give [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros) from the VimTips wiki:

> Note however, that the above method using :let will not work as expected for any macros which you make ending in a < CR > or < NL > character (carriage return or newline). This is because, as documented in :help :let-@, Vim will treat the register as "linewise" under these conditions. The reason for this is to make registers set with :let act "the right way" when dealing with yanked/deleted text, but it can cause headaches when dealing with recorded macros. Possible workarounds include using the setreg() function or adding "no-op" commands to the end of the macro, such as a < ESC >. See the discussion on vim_dev about unexpected behavior of the :let command for details.

So you have a few options: use `setreg()` or add some kind of no-op sequence (< ESC >) to the string when you use `let`.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks for your speedy and comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert special keys easily using let, just use double quotes:

```
:let @a="ihey\<Esc>\<Return>\<Return>"
```

If you use single quotes vim will insert:
`\<Esc>\<Return>\<Return>` instead of their functions